# .Net Framework Assistant 1.0 on Firefox 3.6.10 fail

Tags: windows-xp, browser, .net-framework, firefox-3.6

I have 2 computers with the same OS setup, Windowx XP SP3 running firefox 3.6.10 and one has .Net Framework Assistant 1.0 installed and working on the firefox complements and the 2nd one has it saying that it is not compatible with firefox 3.6.10.

What can I do to fix it and/or reinstall the same or what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i found to re-install it was the follow:

1. Remove it completly using the 2nd method at http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B963707&x=14&y=6
2. Went to Windows Update Page and installed it once again.

With this it worked fine and there is no more conflict on firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This extension requires version 3.5 SP1 of the .NET Framework to be installed.  Is it possible you don't have that on the second computer?

Comment: Both have it specially the one that has it with malfunction because it has visual studio 2008 pro which install 3.5 SP1 by default, i also made sure of it checking the programs and updates installed.